# Play framework JavaWs exception java.io.IOException: Remotely Closed

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I am trying to call a post() on URL using Play Framework and I am getting following exception. I am new to play framework. What could be happening here?

I am using Play 2.2.3.

I am calling post() on pla.libs.WS.WSRequestHolder object.

Here is my exception:

```
2015-05-12 00:34:21,042 - [DEBUG] - verify: returning true
2015-05-12 00:34:21,262 - [ERROR] - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.io.IOException: Remotely Closed [id: 0xdbe93d29, 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:55827 :> remoteHost/remoteip:443]
2015-05-12 00:34:21,271 - [ERROR] -

! @6m5hfogf0 - Internal server error, for (POST) [/document/envelopes] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IOException: Remotely Closed [id: 0xdbe93d29, 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:55827 :> remoteHost/remoteIp:443]]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:260) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$$anon$1.execute(Execution.scala:43) [play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
java.io.IOException: Remotely Closed [id: 0xdbe93d29, 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:55827 :> remoteHost/remoteIp:443]
        at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.channelClosed(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1388) ~[async-http-client-1.7.18.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:88) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleUpstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:142) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:570) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelClosed(FrameDecoder.java:371) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelClosed(HttpClientCodec.java:221) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:88) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleUpstream(HttpClientCodec.java:92) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.cleanup(FrameDecoder.java:493) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelClosed(FrameDecoder.java:371) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelClosed(SslHandler.java:1605) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:88) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelClosed(Channels.java:468) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:376) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:58) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.closeOutboundAndChannel(SslHandler.java:1457) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleDownstream(SslHandler.java:590) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleDownstream(HttpClientCodec.java:97) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleDownstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:109) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:197) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.exceptionCaught(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1520) ~[async-http-client-1.7.18.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleUpstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:142) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleUpstream(HttpClientCodec.java:92) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.exceptionCaught(SslHandler.java:695) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) ~[na:1.7.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) ~[na:1.7.0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) ~[na:1.7.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out yesterday. This exception is happening because I need to install digital ssl certificate and configure it to use for the post call.